# How Can I Make My Highly Modular Project Easy for End Users to Compile?

Tags: c, makefile, project, compilation, modularity

I am working on a relatively large set of serial code C-code libraries, which will then be parallelized in CUDA by my collaborators.

For this project my code essentially boils down to

```
#include "Initialize.cpp"
#include "PerformMoves.cpp"
#include "CollectResults.cpp"

main() 
{
   //DECLARE General Vars

   Initialize();

   for (unsigned int step=0; step < maxStep; step++)
   {
      PerformMoves();
   }

   CollectResults();
}
```

Now the steps I perform inside Initialize and PerformMoves will be very different depending on what kind of simulation I'm building.  Speed is of the utmost performance as my code is a Monte Carlo simulation that will be performing millions of moves, each of which involves potentially thousands of calculations.  Thus I want to avoid any unnecessary conditionals.

Thus I essentially want different "plug and play" C modules, e.g.

> InitializeSimType1.cpp
>   InitializeSimType2.cpp
>   InitializeSimType3.cpp
>
> PerformMovesType1.cpp
>   PerformMovesType2.cpp
>   PerformMovesType3.cpp
>
> ....

Each optimized for a certain type of simulation procedure, without the "fluff" of large conditionals to handle a variety of cases.

Currently I have two different types of simulations, and just have these in two different folders and compile as follows:

> g++ Main.cc Initialize.cpp
>   PerformMoves.cpp CollectResults.cpp -o
>   MC_Prog

I would like to move to some sort of conditional compilation scheme, where I have some sort config file where I specify options and it grabs the correct cpp files and compiles them.

I would assume that a makefile+config files is my best bet, but beyond basic targets and very linear compilation I'm pretty novice to the world of complex makefiles.

What are some good ways that I could create a list-driven compilation system, that would allow users with very basic C knowledge to easily build a target with the modules they want.  My end users won't have a great deal of makefile knowledge (or programming knowledge in general), so a complex system on their end is out of the question.  I want them basically to have a transparent configuration-file driven system that will allow them to pick one Initialize module, one PerformMoves module, and one CollectResults module.  Once they've modified this configuration file with their picks, I want them to be able to do a single-command compilation.

In other words I want to be able to create a README that directs users:

1. Input these entries in this config file 
   (gives config file name, options to put for each config file entry)...
2. Compile using this command (gives single command)

I know this is a rather abstract and complex question, but I know there are some Makefile/c experts out there who could offer me some good guidance.

Comment: Well For One You Shouldn't Use So Many Capitals In Your Instructions.

Comment: In my actual code I follow Microsoft's suggested MSDN naming convention, which is (last I checked) to cap the first letter of all words inside vars.  The above code I just tapped out really quickly to give a rough idea of what I was trying to do.  I understand there's lot's of different ideas about variable casing, but I figured MSFT was a pretty good authority, so just stick with their suggestions.  Is that a bad idea?

Comment: Always seems to be better to use underscores for editing and dinking with code. MS is, after all, the company that came up with hungarian notation.

Comment: @Paul" Microsoft standardized a brain-dead and pointless version of Hungarian notation with the effect of getting people to hate the whole idea, but there *is* a good way to implement it, and at times it is worthwhile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of a couple of similar build systems:

1. When you build GCC it builds libraries with helper routines (eg `libgcc.a`).  It wants to ensure that only the necessary functions link into your program.  Since the unit of linker granularity is a single `.o` it builds one `.c` file dozens of times with different `-D_enable_xxx` options to turn on each function individually.  Then it uses `ar` to build the resulting `.o` into a `.a` which you can link against to get only what you need.
2. The X window server has several functions which perform largely identical operations except that the math in the very innermost loop is different.  For example, it might `xor` or `and` or `or` bits together.  It doesn't want a conditional in its inner loop either so it builds the same file over and over with different `-D_math_xor` options to produce dozens of `.o` each with one function that performs the specific math operation wrapped in the looping function.  It uses all of the `.o` (because the operation is actually selected by the X client, not at compile time) so the `.a` technique is not important.

It sounds like you could use a mix of those to produce a library of `.o` where each one is pre-compiled with your specific options and then rebuild just `main.c` over and over calling different functions and linking against your libaray.

Based on your comments below, here are a few other ideas:

1. When you build binutils, GCC, glibc, etc you unpack the source distribution but you *don't build inside the source tree*.  Instead you `mkdir obj-mytarget; cd obj-mytarget; ../path/to/gcc/configure --options...; make`  The `configure` script creates `config.h` and a `Makefile` specific to the options (and, of course, the system capabilities).  One big advantage of this setup is that all of the build products (from `.o` to executables) for that set of options are self-contained and do not interfere with builds using other options.
2. The classic BSD kernel configuration is done by editing a file (idiomatically given an all caps name like `GENERIC` which produces the default kernel or `LINT` which turns on everything for static analysis purposes) and then invoking `config CONFNAME`.   `config` parses the simple config file and creates a directory tree named after the file.  The directory tree contains a `Makefile` and various `.h` files to control the build.  Same basic advantages as the method above.
3. avr-libc (a libc for Atmel AVR microcontrollers) automates the above approaches by automatically creating target directories for dozens of microcontrollers (with variations in memory size, peripheral availability, etc) and building *all* of the variations in a single pass.  The result is many libraries, providing a cross build environment capable of targeting any AVR.  You could use a similar idea to automatically build every permutation of your program.

Comment: Hi Ben, 
Thanks for the good advice!  I see both GCC and the X Window Server are using some sort of custom macro-driven compilation.  This is getting closer what I want, but not exactly what I was hoping for. 

This kind of system seems like it would be good for compiling multiple predefined targets which share common drop-in components (think entrees at a restaurant which share ingredients).

My goal would be to have instead a config file that supplies this information and a single make target for my central executable (think a salad bar where you can pick your items to get your net entree).

Comment: To finish my thought, that way the user can modify this file, say `CONFIG`, and then type `make MC_Prog` and it will automatically select the right drop-in components via the variable/value pairs in the configuration file.

That way the end users doesn't have to worry about any complex flags or a ton of targets, they simply get a simple to understand CONFIG file and a single primary make target (along with appropriate ancillary targets like clean, etc.).

I'm assuming what I need is some sort of text parsing/conditional logic inside the makefile itself...

Comment: or a script system that parses the config file and auto-generates/calls an appropriate makefile.  

I'm thinking that MAY be my best bet -- have say a *.py script that parses the var/value pairs in `CONFIG` (ignoring comment lines) that spits out and calls a makefile.

That way they just modify the values in `CONFIG` to one of the options given in the comments, then run the script and the compilation system does its trick without any complexity for them.

Does that sound like a good solution?

Comment: I added more examples which approach the problem from a higher level.